# Nested Accordion JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a simple Accordion menu whicih I got from jsfiddle only.
I want to make it nested.

Click [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bigvax/hEApL/)

Posting the code in case jsfiddle is not working:

> HTML

```
<div class="accordion-expand-holder">
<button type="button" class="open">Expand all</button>
<button type="button" class="close">Collapse all</button>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
    <p>Para 1</p>
</div>

<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
    <p>Para 2</p>
</div>

<h3>Section 3</h3>
<div>
    <p>Para 3</p>
    <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<h3>Section 4</h3>
<div>
    <p>para 4 - 1</p>
    <p>Para 4 - 2</p>
</div>
```

> JQuery:

```
$(function () {
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible:true,
    active:false
});
var icons = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" );
$('.open').click(function () {
    $('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').attr({
        'aria-selected': 'true',
        'tabindex': '0'
    });
    $('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.header).addClass(icons.headerSelected);
    $('.ui-accordion-content').addClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
        'aria-expanded': 'true',
        'aria-hidden': 'false'
    }).show();
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('.close').removeAttr("disabled");
});
$('.close').click(function () {
    $('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all').attr({
        'aria-selected': 'false',
        'tabindex': '-1'
    });
    $('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.headerSelected).addClass(icons.header);
    $('.ui-accordion-content').removeClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
        'aria-expanded': 'false',
        'aria-hidden': 'true'
    }).hide();
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('.open').removeAttr("disabled");
});
$('.ui-accordion-header').click(function () {
    $('.open').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('.close').removeAttr("disabled");

});
});
```

> CSS:

```
body {
font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:65%;
}
.accordion-expand-holder {
margin:10px 0;
}
.accordion-expand-holder .open, .accordion-expand-holder .close {
margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

I want these menus to be nested.
I am new to JQuery please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

just see this fiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/hEApL/148/

```
<div class="accordion-expand-holder">
    <button type="button" class="open">Expand all</button>
    <button type="button" class="close">Collapse all</button>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
     <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>

    <!-- inner accordian -->    
<div id="accordion1" >
     <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>


</div>
           <!-- inner accordian --> 

    </div>


</div>
```

your js :

```
// Accordion - Expand All #01 
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false
    });
        $("#accordion1").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false
    });



    var icons = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" );
    $('.open').click(function () {
        $('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').attr({
            'aria-selected': 'true',
            'tabindex': '0'
        });
        $('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.header).addClass(icons.headerSelected);
        $('.ui-accordion-content').addClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
            'aria-expanded': 'true',
            'aria-hidden': 'false'
        }).show();
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.close').removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all').attr({
            'aria-selected': 'false',
            'tabindex': '-1'
        });
        $('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.headerSelected).addClass(icons.header);
        $('.ui-accordion-content').removeClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
            'aria-expanded': 'false',
            'aria-hidden': 'true'
        }).hide();
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.open').removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $('.ui-accordion-header').click(function () {
        $('.open').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.close').removeAttr("disabled");

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why it is showing contents under the second menu item in a short textarea like scrollable window? How can I get a div there?

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine nested accordion jquery

https://codepen.io/brenden/pen/Kwbpyj

**Example Below**

```js
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  
    var $this = $(this);
  
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600');
* { box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif; font-weight: 300; }
a { text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }
body { width: 40%; min-width: 300px; max-width: 400px; margin: 1.5em auto; color: #333; }
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; }
ul .inner { padding-left: 1em; overflow: hidden; display: none; }
ul li { margin: .5em 0; }
ul li a.toggle { width: 100%; display: block; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.78); color: #fefefe; padding: .75em; border-radius: 0.15em; transition: background .3s ease; }
ul li a.toggle:hover { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 2</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>Option 1</li>
      <li>Option 2</li>
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 3</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
            blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner #2</a>
        <div class="inner">
          <p>
            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Item 4</a>
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
        <ul class="inner">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="toggle">Another nested element</a>
            <div class="inner">
              <p>
                As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
              </p>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
              </p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li>Option 2</li>
      
      <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```