# Nested accordion collapse issue

Tags: jquery

I have created multilevel nested accordion. Here is the **[Demo](http://amar-pawar.com/ForumHelp/MultilevelAccordian/test.html)** link. If you click on **Test01** it expands and we can see child level accordion (e.g. My company only sells Software products. New login screen?).

When I click on `My company only sells Software products. New login screen?` it suddenly collapses.

My concern is that child level accordion should work. i.e. it should expand too as like **Test01**

Comment: I have added the demo link, please see above ("Demo").

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541113/nested-accordion-jquery  your markup doesn't look like you are actually nesting accordions.

Comment: problem is that nesting should be done with the existinf structure. But I am not able to create this. The code was only for one level accordion. So I have edited that and tried to create multilevel, but I couldn't. Need solution.